# Why do I get an "Error running 'autoreconf'" error using RVM to install ruby-2.0.0-head?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to install Ruby 2.0 via RVM in my Mac OSX Lion system, but I keep bumping into this error:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
HEAD is now at a653ba0 merge revision(s) 42720: [Backport #8829]
From git://github.com/ruby/ruby
 * branch            ruby_2_0_0 -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Copying from repo to src path...
ruby-2.0.0-head - #autoreconf........
Error running 'autoreconf',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1378234760_ruby-2.0.0-head/autoreconf.log
Skipping configure step, 'configure' does not exist, did autoreconf not run successfully?
ruby-2.0.0-head - #post-configuration
ruby-2.0.0-head - #compiling.
Error running 'make -j8',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1378234760_ruby-2.0.0-head/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

My autoconf version is 2.68 and RVM is 1.22.3.

Has anyone had the same problem before?

Comment: Have you installed other Rubies correctly? Do you have the developer tools installed? What does "please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1378234760_ruby-2.0.0-head/make.log" tell you?

Comment: a note - you are trying to install 2.0.0-head which means development code for the 2.0.0 branch, it is not equal with the latest release patchlevel of 2.0.0, to use the latest released version run: `rvm install 2.0.0`

Comment: @theTinMan, yep I managed to install older version or ruby (ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, etc..).  This only happened when I tried to install ruby 2.0.
I already tried checking the make.log and it only says:
[2013-09-04 02:59:22] make
current path: /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-head
command(2): make -j8
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: @mpapis.  Thanks for the info.  Yep I already tried that as well. Got the same error.

Comment: please try `rm -rf /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0*; rvm --debug install 2.0.0`, make sure to include full output and the mentioned log files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to fix the issue. It was a perl version problem.
The autoconf log was saying something like "This perl not built to support threads".
I had an older version of perl:

---

$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3) built for darwin-multi-2level

---

I did 'sudo port upgrade perl5' and after it successfully updated everything went smoothly.

Thanks for the help everyone! :)